# fetchEntityByKey Queries against an invalid api route

Tags: breeze

My entity name is "Products" but in my WebApi the route is defined as "GetProducts" so in default it will query against /api/Products? instead of /api/GetProducts, is there any way to specify where it should fetch the data from the server if it can't find what i want in the cache.

So far i got this

```
manager.fetchEntityByKey("Products", productId, true)
    .then(fetchSucceeded)
    .fail(queryFailed);
```

This will call `http://localhost:1990/breeze/Products?$filter=Id%20eq%201`

But i want it to call `http://localhost:1990/breeze/GetProducts?$filter=Id%20eq%201` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change entity's default resourceName(that hits the breeze webapi method name) with

```
manager.metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName("GetProducts", "Product")
```

But be sure the code above is executed when promise of **manager.fetchMetadata() is resolved**:

```
manager.fetchMetadata().then(function(){
    manager.metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName(...);
})
```

If `setEntityTypeForResourceName` is called before metadata has loaded you will get an **error**, i.e

> Unable to locate 'entityTypeName' of: Product

Comment: The other two answers were actually true the work but they weren't as detailed as this so i will accept this one, sorry guys but i can't rate yet when i can i will rate the other two answers as well.

Answer (score 2):

There's also another option to specify this on the server. With WebApi 2, you can use the RouteAttribute on your controller action to customize the routing.

See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

EDIT:

On the client, the Breeze EntityType has a property called defaultResourceName which you can modify as well to tell Breeze which default resource name to use if only an entity type name is specified.

```
var productType = metadataStore.getEntityType('Products');
productType.defaultResourceName = 'GetProducts';

//Will create fetch request to breeze/GetProducts
manager.fetchEntityByKey('Products', productId);
```

Comment: The problem was me using route attributes giving whatever route i want while breeze is bitching about it's conventions.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I misunderstood your question there. Answer revised.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Resource for the given entity type which would hit the resource instead -

```
    manager.metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName('GetProducts', 'Products');
```

But as a note it seems like a design flaw to name your entity `Products` instead of `Product`.

Comment: it's entity framework pluralizing :), i'll try your solution if it works i'll select it as the right answer.

Comment: it's giving me an error entityTypeName cannot be found

Comment: Is it saying Unable to locate entityTypeName of type Products or something else?  Are you sure you have called metadata before you try to set the resource?

Comment: yes i did and i called manager.metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName('GetProducts', 'Products'); inside .then()

Comment: it's Ok don't bother your self i am gonna change my Api routes to match breeze conventions rather than inventing the wheel.